# loading file content to NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm using this code to load content to NSArray and it seem to work fine however Instrument to detect leaks point that there is a problem that I can't put my finger on:

```
    - (void) loadPlan: (NSString  *) fName
    {

        short j1;

        fName= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",  fName];

        [self NewCase];

        NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docDirectory = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:fName];
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

        if (!fileExists) return;

        NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


        NSArray *chunks = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];


      for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
         {
            InputV[i] = [[chunks objectAtIndex: i+5] doubleValue];
         }


    ...    
      for (j1 = 0; j1 <= 10; j1++)
        {

            GroupMode[j1] = [[chunks objectAtIndex: 206+j1]   retain];   
        }


     ...
}
```

and on a init method someplace i have:

```
for (j1 = 0; j1 <= 10; j1++)
     {
           GroupMode[j1] = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
     }
```

Instrument points to the NSAraay *chunks  line code but i'm not sure what's the issue. Do i need to release it at some point ?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: How are you managing memory? Are you using ARC, GC or manual memory management?

Comment: @Analog File I'm using whatever the default method is, i didn't initiate anything. for example if i have : pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:91];
 then in the dealloc method i have [Items release];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you mention being able to call release. Therefore you are not using ARC and since I noticed you tagged with iphone you are not using GC. This leaves manual memory management.

The problem seems to be that either the chunks array or some chunks themseves are overretained (or underreleased). You are not showing all the code, so it's hard to say.

Make sure you do not retain either of them somewhere else in the code you did not show. Maybe show us the rest of the loadPlan method implementation.

edit: Now that you added more code, I can also expand this answer.

Answer this question: where is the retain call to the chunks matched with a release?

Also what is the declaration of GroupMode? It seems to be just an array of pointers. If so you probably need to release the old value before setting the new one.

Comment: I edit my original post and added some relevant code. I already see that i don't have to Alloc when i do InitWithFormat and probably i have to release in loadPlan method before i put chunks values. I just want to make sure that i'll still have GrouPMode values along the program and be able do modify them as needed. Please comment.

Comment: you are correct NSString *GroupMode[11];  array of pointers.  Just the same i added the matched release etc and the issue resolved. Now i see a leak in a different part of test i'm doing using Instrument (i'll try to resolve it or post it). I take it that i need to resolve all before submitting the app to Apple.. MY App is universal and is working on both iPad and iPhone. Is there a way like GC (i'm not sure what it is or ARC) that will release me from handling memory management ? is it easier? Thanks for your input.

Comment: I posted another answer with more details and a suggestion you do not use a plain array (you commented while I was editing it). GC does not work on iPhone and iPad. ARC should work, but only on new versions of  iOS. It may be easier, but I have the feeling that learning how to do it manually will help you understand your own code much better. Switch to ARC when you feel you actually understand what ARC automagically does for you anyway. Using ARC for you now may be like learning to drive while sitting on the passenger seat.

Comment: Oh, in case you were wondering, GC stands for Garbage Collection, it's automatic memory reclaiming. DOes not work on iOS and the feeling is that Apple does not consider it the preferred way to do things on Macs either. ARC stands for Automatic Reference Counting and more or less means the compiler is very smart and adds retain and release calls automatically. Check Apple docs for info on both.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try another answer based on what you posted.

I'm assuming GroupMode is an instance variable of some class and is declared like this:

NSString* GroupMode[11];

The second loop in loadPlan should be:

```
  for (j1 = 0; j1 <= 10; j1++)
    {
        NSString* aChunk = [chunks objectAtIndex: 206+j1];
        if ( GroupMode[j1] != aChunk ) {
            [GroupMode[j1] release];
            GroupMode[j1] = [aChunk retain];
        }   
    }
```

You should do something similar every time you change an element of GroupMode and you should make sure you release all GroupMode held objects in the dealloc method of that class.

I however suggest you do not use plain arrays and instead switch to using NSArray and/or NSMutableArray.

Comment: yes I  see what you mean. Thank you for taking the time to help, I already feel more confident in my men management skills:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer:

["componentsSeparatedByString" Memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299797/componentsseparatedbystring-memory-leak)

The problem is probably that something using the results is over-retaining the stuff from chunks. Instruments is pointing at this line because it's where the memory was first allocated, but it may not be the source of your problem.

Comment: thank you for the link and suggestion , i will check it to learn more.